# How to get shop owner's plan limits from Shopify?

Tags: api, e-commerce, shopify

According to current Shopify plans, there are limits to SKUs and storage that the user is bound to because of her plan. Is it possible to find out how much the user have consumed out of that limit? e.g. How many SKUs have been consumed/left and/or how much storage have been used so far or is left?

Answer (score 0):

Just query all their products and you get the SKU count. If you download all their assets, and add up the sizes of them, you'd get their storage approximately.

Comment: I definitely thought of doing this. Getting the SKUs count is not too much of an overhead, but getting all the assets seems to be a bad idea especially for stores with a lot of media.